# Why does the accept rate calculation include unanswered questions ?

Tags: support, accept-rate, unanswered-questions

I am used to asking many questions on Ask Ubuntu, but a few of them remain unanswered. Maybe they are too hard to answer or too technical. But this is not the point.

My accept rate is therefore lower than I would expect it to be. It might discourage people to answer my other questions, for fear that I will not approve their answers. It looks like a vicious circle.

Could the accept rate calculation please do not include unanswered questions ?

Comment: it does not include unanswered questions, see flute's answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [blog post that announced the idea of accept rate](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/08/new-question-asker-features/) said that to be counted:

> - Questions must not be community wiki.
> - Questions must not be closed.
> - Questions must be more than 3 days old.
> - *Questions must have at least 1 answer.*

So unless the SE team have changed their mind this is likely a bug.

---

However remember that most of the time accept rate isn't really important. I almost never look at people's accept rates, except for when questions like this come up on meta.

I'll leave you with a [quote from our parent site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67490/unanswered-questions-and-accept-rate); the last sentence is very true in my opinion.

> #### What does the accept rate mean?
>
> - If the stat doesn’t appear at all, it’s a new user, or someone who rarely
>     asks questions.
> - If you see a low percentage, it’s a user who asks a lot of questions but
>     accepts almost no answers.
> - If you see a high percentage, it’s an engaged user, someone who
>     frequently goes back and interacts
>     with their questions after asking.
> - *If you see a middle of the road percentage, it’s an experienced user
>     who understands what accepted answers
>     are for.*